# Make values of row (different names) into column -- complicated spread?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have this data frame, where each question has two sub parts (q1, q1_p2). I would like to move the answer for the second subpart to be on the same row.

```
question     answer
q1           bleh
q1_p2        bah
q2           meh
q2_p2        bleh
```

Basically, something like this.

```
question     answer     p2
q1           bleh       bah
q2           meh        bleh
```

I usually would use something like spread for things like this, but I don't know how to incorporate that fact that the value for each question that will be spread is not identical.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your full data set follows the structure of your example, then this will suffice,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(question = sub('_.*', '', question)) %>% 
 mutate(new = seq(n())) %>% 
 spread(new, answer) %>% 
 rename(answer = `1`, p2 = `2`) %>% 
 ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 × 3
#  question answer     p2
#*    <chr> <fctr> <fctr>
#1       q1   bleh    bah
#2       q2    meh   bleh
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this wasn't as neat as I was hoping I could get but it works.

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table("question" = c("q1", "q1_p2", "q2", "q2_p2"), "answer" = c("bleh","bah","meh","bleh"))
dt$q = sapply(dt$question ,function(x) strsplit(x, "_")[[1]][1])
dt[ , "Row" := 1:.N]

dt[ , "New" := ifelse(nchar(gsub("\\D","",question)) == 1, "answer", gsub("(.+(?=p\\d+))", "",question, perl = T)), by = .(Row)]

dt = dcast(dt, q ~ New, value.var = "answer")
> dt
    q answer   p2
1: q1   bleh  bah
2: q2    meh bleh
```

Comment: I might have done a little too much. I didn't see the comment about only 2 sub parts. This will work for any amount.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
separate(df1, question, into = c("question", "value")) %>% 
       mutate(value = replace(value, is.na(value), "answer")) %>% 
       spread(value, answer)
#  question answer   p2
#1       q1   bleh  bah
#2       q2    meh bleh
```